# Php array without set parents to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have found many SO answers that are close to my issue but,in most cases, there is already a parent-child reference in the array.

I get a json that, decoded, gets the following array:

```
$refs = [
    0 =>
        [
            'type' => '1',
            'ref' => 'main-doc',
        ],
    1 =>
        [
            'type' => '2',
            'ref' => 'if-refs',
        ],
    2 =>
        [
            'type' => '3',
            'ref' => 'decision',
        ],
    3 =>
        [
            'type' => '2',
            'ref' => 'secondo',
        ],
    4 =>
        [
            'type' => '1',
            'ref' => 'ref-ric',
        ],
    5 =>
        [
            'type' => '3',
            'ref' => 'also',
        ],
    6 =>
        [
            'type' => '1',
            'ref' => 'june-happy',
        ],
    7 =>
        [
            'type' => '1',
            'ref' => 'eh-bien',
        ],
    8 =>
        [
            'type' => '2',
            'ref' => 'l-assemblee',
        ],
    9 =>
        [
            'type' => '3',
            'ref' => 'retour',
        ],
    10 =>
        [
            'type' => '1',
            'ref' => 'postcard',
        ],
];
```

I am trying to turn this into a hierarchical array.Although there are no parents, the type is a quoted number.

**Goal:** What I am trying to get (as snippet):

```
    0 =>
        [
            'type' => '1',
            'ref' => 'main-doc',
            'children'=>[
                0 =>
                    [
                        'type' => '2',
                        'ref' => 'if-refs',
                        'children'=>[
                            0 =>
                                [
                                    'type' => '3',
                                    'ref' => 'decision',
                                    'children' =>[]
                                ],
                        ]
                    ],
                1 =>
                    [
                        'type' => '2',
                        'ref' => 'secondo',
                        'children' =>[]
                    ],
            ]
        ],
```

I *tried* the following, which is vastly and embarrassingly incomplete, but it's to show what I have tried most successfully so far:

```php
$new = [];
$lastType = 1;
foreach ($refs as $k=>$v){
    if($v['type'] == 1){
        $new[] =[
            "type"=>$v["type"],
            "ref"=> $v["ref"],
            "children"=> []
        ];
        $lastType = 1;
    } if($v['type'] > $lastType){
        $getlast = array_key_last($new);
        array_push($new[$getlast]['children'], [
            "type"=>$v["type"],
            "ref"=> $v["ref"],
            "children"=> []
        ]);
        $lastType = $v['type'];
    }
    print_r($new);
}
```

The above does ok with using type '1' as the highest key and pushing anything below that as a child, but it's far from my goal.

- it does not properly nest the array after type '2'. Type '3', for example is nested under type '1'.
- I have not managed to figure out how to decrease the index to its proper number without jumping back to '1'.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you know who the children are? You have three nodes with type=1. What is the rule for determining its children? Is it the closest one that comes after?

Comment: I don't necessarily know because it's a json api response for references that *do* however have their own classification. I just want to be able to sort them out

Comment: You can't write code against a set of rules that you don't know.

Comment: @ryantxr that helps me clarify it. Suppose those where headers. Instead of 'type => 1', it was "header =>h1". You would not always  control how the headers are set in a document. When I pass them to javascript as headers via table of contents libraries, it gets them into a nested array. I am hoping to have it done on the php end.